# in TKInter Why am I getting an error - takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, tkinter

Just learning Python and TKInter and have come across this error in my code. Don't know what I'm missing and hoping someone can help. I've included the button code and the function to show you what I have.

```
def change_font(self):
    self.label_name['font'] = "Sawasdee"

self.button1 = Button(self.myframe2, text="Change font")
self.button1.bind("<Button-1>", self.change_font)
```

Comment: Help us help you. Show a bit more code and please provide the entire error/exception.

Comment: Add `command=self.change_font` to the button creation parameters and delete the bind statement. Bind means an event parameter is passed to the bound function. This is the second argument after self in the error message.

Comment: Thanks very much for the response. Much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

When you bind a function to an event, tkinter will call that function with an argument which represents the event which triggered the function to be called. That is why the error says it expected one argument (self) but got two (self, event).

You need to account for that event parameter even if you don't need it. The easiest way is to make it an optional named parameter:

```
def change_font(self, event=None):
    self.label_name["font"] = "Sawasdee"
```

It's usually incorrect to use `bind` on a button. The `Button` widget accepts an attribute named `command` which can be used to tie the button to a function. In this case, the function will *not* get the event parameter:

```
def change_font(self):
    self.label_name["font"] = "Sawasdee"
self.button1 = Button(self.myframe2, text="ChangeFont", command=change_font)
```

The advantage to using `command` is that it automatically supports not just clicking with the mouse, but also interacting with the button using the keyboard.

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks Bryan for the speedy response. I was adding 'event' on it's own at first and then thought it should have been 'self' but I see now it's both parameters that are needed.  Thanks again